# PHP - Can't end session

Tags: php, session, logout, unset

I have a link in my website after login, that points to "index.php?logout=yes", then in my index.php I have the following code:

```
if ($_GET['logout'] == "yes") {
    session_unset();
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
    $_SESSION = array();
    $_SESSION = [];
}
```

Any ideas why it keeps you logged in and doesn't end the session?

Comment: does it work if you refresh the page manually?

Comment: No, because I have an statement to check if the session is set, and if it is, redirects you to loggedin.php.

Comment: Should the logout statement be before any other checks?

Comment: You have to check first , Is condition becomes true on index.php?logout=yes ?

Comment: `session_unset(); == unset($_SESSION);` and `$_SESSION = array(); == $_SESSION = [];`

Comment: All working. I didn't have the logout if statement early enough in the index. Cheers all!

Comment: Done. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the first lines of code in your index.php if yes use 
header('Location: /');
instead of meta tag for refresh

Answer (score 0):

Please check : [session_destroy](http://php.net/session_destroy)

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

Try this

```
session_unset(); //or unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
session_commit(); // or session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);

header('location: index.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

After a logout, redirect the user to the home page (for example)

And always start the session before using it

```
<php 
session_start();   
if ($_GET['logout'] == "yes") {
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
   session_write_close();
   setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
   session_regenerate_id(true);
   header('location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

public function logout() {

```
    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
        'user_id'       => '',
        'fname'         => '',
        'lname'         => '',
        'gender'        => '',
        'username'      => '',
        'user_comp_id'  => '',
        'user_role'     => '',
        'validated'     => false,
        'plan_name'     => '',
        'plan_restriction' => '',
        'module_leave_bank' => '',
        'module_custom_logo' => '',
        'module_bulk_import' => '',
        'module_custom_rules' => '',
        'module_reports_download' => '',
        'module_integrations' => '',
        'module_chat_support' => '',
        'module_phone_support' => '',
        'users_limit'       => '',
        'leave_policies_limit' => '',
        'ous_limit'         => '',
        'sub_ous_limit'     => '',
        'leave_requests_limit' => '',
        'holidays_limit'    => '',
        'users_count'       => '',
        'leave_policies_count' => '',
        'ous_count'         => '',                       
    ));
    $cookies_id = $this->input->cookie('ci_session', TRUE);
    // $this->db->delete('user_logged_in',array('cookie' => $cookies_id)); // delete the cookies in database
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    redirect('login', 'refresh');
}
```